# How to upgrade the mageto 2.3.3 to 2.3.4

Tags: magento2, magento-upgrade, magento2.3.4

What are the possible ways to upgrade the magento 2.3.3 to 2.3.4 version please tell the suggestions.

Thanks in Advance :)

Answer (score 1):

***Install via Composer:-***

composer require magento/product-community-edition 2.3.4 --no-update

***Install Package:-***
composer require --dev phpunit/phpunit:~6.2.0 friendsofphp/php-cs-fixer:~2.10.1 lusitanian/oauth:~0.8.10 pdepend/pdepend:2.5.2 sebastian/phpcpd:~3.0.0 squizlabs/php_codesniffer:3.2.2 --no-update

composer remove --dev sjparkinson/static-review fabpot/php-cs-fixer --no-update

***Composer Update:-***

COMPOSER_MEMORY_LIMIT=-1 composer update

***Remove Cache,Page_cache,Generation :-***

rm -rf var/cache/*

rm -rf var/page_cache/*

rm -rf var/generation/*

***After Perform Command :-***

php bin/magento setup:upgrade

php bin/magento indexer:reindex

php bin/magento cache:flush

php bin/magento cache:clean

Comment: Thanks @Naeem Dhattiwala is it possible to upgrade via admin panel